# Determine how many physical/hardware USB host controllers I have

Tags: linux, usb

Out of simple curiosity, I'm trying to determine how many hardware USB host controllers my machine has.  `lsub` lists seven root hubs, and `lspci -v` and `lshw` both list seven host controllers.  I'm *guessing* that most of these are virtual controllers which provide different views of a smaller number of hardware controllers (since my machine only has four USB ports), but that's just a guess.  Are there any commands that will tell me about the actual hardware, or any ways of analyzing the output of the above commands to figure things out?

Comment: The seven likely include USB2 - Enhanced Host Controller Interface (EHCI) and USB1 - Universal Host Controller (UHCI) and possibly USB3 -  eXtensible Host Controller Interface (xHCI)  listings.